# How to view facebook public information

Tags: php, facebook

I want to view user's public information in facebook, If I am not logged in I can only see the user's Favorites, Music, Other, Others With a Similar Name etc. But if I am logged in, I can see the user's info such as Work and Education, Family, Contact info etc.

Is there a way for me to view the user's public information without logging on facebook? I want to do this because I need to get the page source of the profile (with info like Contact info etc.) using PHP and then I'll put the source in a text file.

Comment: This sounds totally legit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get publicly available data of any user using Graph API or FQL through any of the SDK like [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk). The public data that you can retrieve are the one that requires no access token or app access token in the permission field in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) of user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the users ID you can hit http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id} in your browser

Comment: I got this already and return me default parameters as json. What I want to get is the user's public info such as bday, address, birthday work etc (viewable public info) without logging in.

Comment: You’re not supposed to get that info, especially not without being logged in. Use the API, and ask for the right permissions to read the information you want from the user. (Although not all of that is available, f.e. address and phone number are not.)

Comment: Yes these aren't considered public params. They're extended permissions and require the user to consent to you accessing them. You can see a list of them here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: is there a way for me to get access token for User Data Permission? It is what I am looking for, not the extended one. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by user data permissions? It's all user data but it's broken up to require specific permissions for different data types. If you're asking if there is a permissions for all user data then no, that doesn't exist.